# Moving from ionic 3 browser testing to Ionic DevApp & Mobile testing

Tags: laravel, ionic-framework, cors

I originally built a web site with laravel. I have now made it into an app with ionic, creating an API with laravel.  Everything functions correctly in the browser as I have added ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*'); to my calls with in laravel.  I am now looking to start to add in needed functionality such as the camera.  When I use Ionic’s DevApp and the ionic serve –c command, I literally get nothing to return from laravel.

- The images from the laravel public directory do not return
- On ios, on running the basic login procedure, nothing is returned in the console
- On android, on running the basic login procedure, I get the following
  error error

  error - [object ProgressEvent]
  message - Http failure response for (unknown url): 0 Unknown Error
  name - HttpErrorResponse
  status - 0
  statusText - Unknown Error

**Auth Page in browser**

```
ionViewDidLoad AuthLoginPage
ionViewWillEnter Login
doGetUser_exact No token in localstorage
onSignIn
{"email":" @yahoo.com","password":"zxc"}
loginValidate - http://zzz/api/auth/login
sub
onSignIn - loginfo
{access_token: "123", token_type: "bearer", expires_in: 7200}
token before storage - Bearer  123
login - vUserNew    
{"id":1,"name}
email - @yahoo.com
```

**Auth Log From iPhone - DEVAPP**

```
ionViewDidLoad AuthLoginPage
ionViewWillEnter Login
doGetUser_exact No token in localstorage
onSignIn
{"email":" @yahoo.com","password":"zxc"}
loginValidate - http://zzz/api/auth/login
```

---this is where it stops

I also added the following code to the .htaccess folder in the public directory

```
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "GET,POST,OPTIONS,DELETE,PUT"
```

---this actually did not help as it blocked the browser from completing login validation

I’m just wondering what my next steps are.

- What else would need to add anything else relating to CORS? How is the going to work when I actually do deploy to production?
- Would there be a firewall issue?
- Does DevApp currently work?
- Do I hope my phone up directly to the computer
- Do I have to deploy the app to continue working with it

Any help would be appreciated as I have exhausted my search on the subject.

Comment: When you run `ionic serve` and try log in from the browser, what response headers and response do you get? Could you include a screenshot from DevTools?

Comment: honestly, when i built this in the browser i did a lot of logging in the console and it works properly - logging in and out - showing all the steps it should hit in my log in process. when i run ionic serve -c and go on my phone, i submit the login - it gets to the post and basically stops from what's seen in the console. I'll add the consoles above for the auth post

Answer (score 0):

Have you whitelisted your domain? The [Cordova Whitelist plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist) comes standard with the `ionic start` apps. Do you have it and the relevant tags in `config.xml`?

```
<access launch-external="yes" origin="*" />
<allow-navigation href="*" />
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
```

Comment: i had 2 of the 4 of these, and yes, i needed the whitelist to connect to the browser initially. i added the two i didn't have and got the same result. it's connecting to ionic but not returning anything from the virtual host address where laravel and its assets reside.

Comment: Have you compiled the app and run it natively?

Comment: What do you see in the server logs when you try to connect from the Dev App?

Comment: I have not used the error log very much on my local host.  The error log was empty when I found it.  I changed the config ‘log’ settings to errorlog and syslog, cached the configuration, and still nothing was logged when I reran on the device.  I know I have errors log in my production environment, but I’m not sure why they are not here. First time I haven't been able to get at the error when it comes to Laravel. Any advice?

Comment: Do you get server logs when you run the app in the browser but no logs at all when you run it on the device?

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I think my problem has to do with my local setup and use of wamp.  I’ve tried to do everything I can to fix this communication issue and it doesn’t go way.  I’m not sure I will have this problem and when I upload to my server.  I will probably have other issues to deal with, but I think I should be OK here or at least I hope.